# JMeter Distributed testing on EC2 Master and EC2 slave machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, distributed-testing

I want to configure JMeter for distributed testing in aws Ec2 instances. I followed the Jmeter manual still facing issues. Both Slave and Master are aws Ec2 instances. Both are from same region under same subnet. I have turned off firewall in both master and slave.I even diabled rmi ssl with this command server.rmi.ssl.disable=true, configured the remote host with slave ip on the master. before starting the execution i have launched the jmeter-server.bat on the aws slave. I tried to run a simple http request through slave and got the below given error.

**Connection refused to host:<>; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**

I have disabled firewall in both slave and master machines. JMeter & Java versions are the same. Is there
a way to resolve this connection issue from master to slave through JMeter by running the test

Answer (score 0):

If your masters/slaves are in the same [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) - you can use private IP addresses, otherwise you will have to go make sure to use public IP addresses (or DNS hostnames)

Also make sure that the following ports are open in [AWS security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/working-with-security-groups.html):

- 1099 (or whatever you set as the `server.port`)
- the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
- the port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`

More information:

- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)